# Proof from axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$: every natural number has remainder $0$ or $1$ or $2$ when divided by $3$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, arithmetic, peano-axioms

Using only the axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$, I want to prove this fact. It came up in a previous year's exam paper, and seems more difficult than I had anticipated... The question was to sketch the idea, but I thought it was a good exercise to try and show every gory detail of the proof.

*My question is whether this proof is correct (in particular the details such as the overlines, and use of* only *the axioms)?* Moreover, if anyone knows of a shorter proof, I would be interested to see it.

---

#### Proof

First I have stated this in the language of arithmetic:
$$\forall n((
\exists q(\overline{3}\times q=\overline{n})\vee
\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{1}=\overline{n}))\vee
\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{2}=\overline{n})).$$

My aim is to use induction:

> If $\varphi$ is a unary predicate such that:
>
> - $\varphi(0)$ is true, and
> - for every natural number $n$, if $\varphi(n)$ is true, then $\varphi(S(n))$ is true,
>
> then $\varphi(n)$ is true for every natural number $n$.

My choice of $\varphi$ is
$$\varphi(n)=(\psi(n)\wedge\psi(S(n)))\wedge\psi(S(S(n))),$$
where
$$\psi(n)=(
\exists q(\overline{3}\times q=\overline{n})\vee
\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{1}=\overline{n}))\vee
\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{2}=\overline{n}).$$

The base case, $\varphi(0)$ is okay, since the choice of $0$ for $q$ will work in all three $\psi(0)$, $\psi(S(0))$ and $\psi(S(S(0)))$. Now suppose $\varphi(n)$ is true, and look at $\varphi(S(n))$. $\psi(S(n))$ and $\psi(S(S(n)))$ follow from $\varphi(n)$, so it remains only to show that $\psi(S(S(S(n))))$ holds.

Suppose that $\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{2}=\overline{n})$, then by [Tarski's definition of truth in a model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth)(?), there is a natural number $m$ (say) with $\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+\overline{2}=\overline{n}$, and now reasoning in $\mathsf{PA}$ (numbering of axioms are as listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)),
\begin{align}
\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+\overline{2}&=\overline{n}\\
S(S(S(\overline{n})))&=S(S(S(\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+\overline{2}))) &&\text{axiom 2(?), three times}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+S(S(S(\overline{2})))&&\text{axiom 4, three times}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+S(S(S(\overline{2}+0)))&&\text{axiom 3}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+(\overline{2}+S(S(S(0))))&&\text{axiom 4, three times}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+(\overline{2}+\overline{3})&&\text{definition of }\overline{a}\\
&=(\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+\overline{3})+\overline{2}&&\text{properties of addition }(\ast)\\
&=(\overline{3}\times \overline{m+1})+\overline{2}&&\text{axiom 6}.
\end{align}
Then again by Tarksi's definition of truth in a model(?), $\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{2}=S(S(S(\overline{n}))))$, and hence $\psi(S(S(S(n))))$ holds.

Similarly, from $\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{1}=\overline{n})$, we can show $\exists q(\overline{3}\times q+\overline{1}=S(S(S(\overline{n}))))$, and hence $\psi(S(S(S(n))))$ holds.

If $\exists q(\overline{3}\times q=\overline{n})$, then by Tarski's definition of truth in a model(?), there is an $m$ such that $\overline{3}\times \overline{m}=\overline{n}$, and then reasoning in $\mathsf{PA}$:
\begin{align}
\overline{3}\times \overline{m}&=\overline{n}\\
S(S(S(\overline{n})))&=S(S(S(\overline{3}\times \overline{m}))) &&\text{axiom 2(?), three times}\\
&=S(S(S(\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+0))) &&\text{axiom 3}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+S(S(S(\overline{0})))&&\text{axiom 4, three times}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m}+\overline{3}&&\text{definition of }\overline{a}\\
&=\overline{3}\times \overline{m+1}&&\text{axiom 6}.
\end{align}
By Tarski's definition of truth in a model(?) $\exists q(\overline{3}\times q=S(S(S(\overline{n}))))$, and again $\psi(S(S(S(n))))$ holds.

By two applications of the $\vee$-elimination rule of first order logic, from the assumption of $\varphi(n)$, we can deduce $\psi(S(S(S(n))))$, and as mentioned previously this is sufficient to show $\varphi(S(n))$.

Since for all $n$, $\varphi(n)$, in particular $\psi(n)$, which was exactly what was asked ($\forall$-introduction rule).

$(\ast)$  for this step I used that addition is associative and commutative, which holds in $\mathsf{PA}$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_addition_of_natural_numbers) has a proof).

Comment: you have a very very strange way of dealing with quantifiers

Comment: @mercio I do? What is the standard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make this much more difficult than it needs to be: your $\varphi(n)$ used in the induction can just be your $\psi(n)$!